# How to obtain a list of all the skype calls with another user?

Tags: windows-8, skype

I am trying to get a list of all the skype calls I made to another user.

My plan is to take a scrolling screenshot of the chat plane of the Skype window, and get a really tall/thin .jpg or similar and then use a program that detects text in images and get a list of dates/call times/messages.

Googling around I found Greenshot and PicPick but neither work with Skype; could anyone recommend one that would work in Skype? or a completely different approach?

Comment: I think that this is case of the XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please could you edit your question to explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to geta list of all skype calls with another user, so i can check my other records and make sure I am billing them correctly for tutoring time

Comment: Detecting text in images is called "optical character recognition" or OCR. Whether you can get a scrolling screenshot on a desktop is something I don't know. But once you have that screenshot you need to look into OCR utilities to get the text from that image.